# Google ads won't show after using Cloudflare

Tags: adsense, cloudflare

Before I'm using Cloudflare, the Google ads still showed up, but it won't show now. Here's my site http://blog.andra.systems/ (There's should be Google ads on the sidebar). I've tried to remove cache and cookie, also I'm trying with web capture service and no sign of Google ads.

Note: I've turned off DNS and HTTP Proxy, auto minify and rocket loader.

Edit:
The ads strangly appear now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not mixing HTTP content with https.
Example using HTTP Adsense code in a secure SSL enabled website with https address.
if you are making that mistake then change the HTTP code with https that would solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not using any SSL, and here's my script <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> it should not be a problem

Comment: your website is showing ads at end of the page have a look. I think the placement of the ad is an issue because that div containing the Ad is not following most of the CSS rules set by custom.css or bootstrap.css or style.css used in your blog.